# PHP Undefined variable with a var changing color

Tags: php

I'm trying to make every second TD in my TABLE (html) another color, and therefore I am using this variable:

```
$bgColor = ($bgColor == "#eee") ? "#fff" : "#eee";
```

And then I'm calling it in my table:

```
<td style='background:<?=$bgColor;?>'></td>
```

But then I get an error: Undefined variable with the $bgColor = ($bgColor etc.);

It's working, but I get that error.

How would I fix this? Normally I've get this error when I've forgot an if(isset()); but thats not the situation here.

Thanks in forward :)

Comment: Add `$bgColor ='';` before first if

Comment: you dont get an error, you most likly get an notice about accessing an undefied value.

Comment: Have you looked into [zebra striping](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css3-zebra-striping-a-table/)? It's CSS3, so it won't work with older browsers, but it is convenient.

Comment: @ThatOtherPerson Actually I havent, but I will do now. It's kinda smart :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bgColor = (isset($bgColor) && $bgColor == "#eee") ? "#fff" : "#eee";
```

Comment: So, I'm using this one. But the @ also works, but for some reason I feel like this is the "right" way to do it. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's because @ simply temporarily suppresses the error, whereas this won't generate an error.  Really, you should just declare the variable beforehand like `$bgColor = null;` or whatever.  And really really, you should just be doing this through stylesheets and classes on the table elements.

Comment: In stylesheets - that's kinda hard when it's getting looped from a database :)

Answer (score 1):

ok you can suppress the error like this, by putting @ symbol infront of the variable $bgColor

```
$bgColor = (@$bgColor == "#eee") ? "#fff" : "#eee";
<td style='background:<?=$bgColor;?>'></td>
```

or simply put isset() function like this..

```
$bgColor = (isset($bgColor) == "#eee") ? "#fff" : "#eee";
<td style='background:<?=$bgColor;?>'></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set $bgColor to a starting value of `#fff` (or `#eee`) otherwise it's undefined for the first row of the table (assuming you have a loop in which you populate the `<td>`'s using the oscillating values for `bgColor` - actually your question leaves pretty much to speculate).

Answer (score -1):

Is it an error, a warning or a notice you are getting? Undefined variables are not a big issue in PHP but if it is a notice you are getting you can control that by turning off the "E_NOTICE" in your error reporting.

Comment: It's not telling me the "error" if I turn off E_NOTICE. But I want my site to be without those small "errors" :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's the proper way to do it. Very nice :)

Comment: Such things go in the "comments section" not in answers